# iOS concurrent: how to use Semaphore instead of barrier?

Tags: swift, concurrency, semaphore

When learning Semaphore, is is possible to use  Semaphore instead of barrier?

Here is the case:

> upload 3 images , then upload other 3 images

With `barrier`,

```
 func workflow() {
        let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "test.concurrent.queue", qos: .background, attributes: .concurrent, autoreleaseFrequency: .workItem)
        queue.async {
            self.uploadImg(idx: "A_0")
        }
        queue.async {
            self.uploadImg(idx: "A_1")
        }
        queue.async {
            self.uploadImg(idx: "A_2")
        }
        queue.async(qos: queue.qos, flags: .barrier) {
            print("group A done")
        }
        queue.async {
            self.uploadImg(idx: "B_0")
        }
        queue.async {
            self.uploadImg(idx: "B_1")
        }
        queue.async {
            self.uploadImg(idx: "B_2")
        }
        
        queue.async(qos: queue.qos, flags: .barrier) {
            print("group B done")
        }
    }

    
    
    func uploadImg(idx info: String){
        Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 1)
        print("img \(info) uploaded")
    }
```

How to use `Semaphore` to do this concurrently?

---

`Semaphore` code added.

I can do the async task one by one.

How to do group - A concurrently , then group B?

`Combine`  is nice option

```
   func workflow() {
           let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "test.concurrent.queue", qos: .background, attributes: .concurrent, autoreleaseFrequency: .workItem)
           let semaphor = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
           queue.async {
               self.uploadImg(idx: "A_0") {
                   semaphor.signal()
               }
           }
           semaphor.wait(timeout: .distantFuture)
           queue.async {
               self.uploadImg(idx: "A_1") {
                   semaphor.signal()
               }
           }
           semaphor.wait(timeout: .distantFuture)
           queue.async {
               self.uploadImg(idx: "B_0") {
               }
           }

       }

       
       
    func uploadImg(idx info: String, handler: @escaping () -> Void){
           Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 1)
           print("img \(info) uploaded")
           handler()
       }
```

Comment: What have you tried with the semaphore, where did you got stuck?

Comment: No. `Semaphore` is not `OperationQueue `. They are different, then two questions.  @Martin R

Comment: @Cristik ,  I have no idea on `semaphore` with what I learned about it. I think `RxSwift` is based on  `semaphore`, and `RxSwift`  can do it. I will try  hard in a few  days. Now  I  have other business to handle.

Comment: Then not sure what you're asking here, are you asking for a semaphore tutorial?

Comment: ask for the answer, I used to use `semaphore ` to do chain request

Comment: if the semaphore tutorial solves, then that is what I ask

Comment: `semaphore ` is easy to use, given a number , signal & wait . @Cristik, if  my question is easy to solve, why not show me the code ?

Comment: Without knowing what your `uploadImg(idx:)` method really does it's hard to guess what you need. Is it async? It should be, but you should also have a callback. Your question is unclear. Forget about semaphores, you should be using Combine to solve this.

Comment: `uploadImg(idx:)` is just a time - consuming task. The request is less meaningful. It is an interview question. When I was asked , I said `Semaphore `. So it is a question technically.

Comment: Do you you have an exact question here? How to use this instead of that is a little bit off-topic on SO.